# Why do I get "ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later." when running stratum mining proxy?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, osx-mountain-lion, zope.interface

The entire return when running "sudo python ./mining_proxy.py" is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./mining_proxy.py", line 67, in <module>
    from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/twisted/__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    _checkRequirements()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Twisted-13.2.0-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/twisted/__init__.py", line 51, in _checkRequirements
    raise ImportError(required + ".")
ImportError: Twisted requires zope.interface 3.6.0 or later.
```

This leads me to believe that zope.interface is not installed.  So I try to install it:

```
sudo easy_install zope.interface
Searching for zope.interface
Best match: zope.interface 4.1.1
Processing zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
zope.interface 4.1.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg
Processing dependencies for zope.interface
Finished processing dependencies for zope.interface
```

I also find [this post](https://github.com/kpdyer/fteproxy/issues/66) which says you basically need to put an **init**.py into the folder.  So I do:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope.interface-4.1.1/__init__.py
```

I try to run mining proxy again, same error.  Please help.

Comment: will you please check `zope.__version__` ?

Comment: @Lafada I'm not sure what you mean.  Folder says 4.1.1.  How do I check otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.

After googling around I found that the touch should be in a different place:

```
sudo touch /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/zope/__init__.py
```

however it didn't work.

I just fixed it using virtualenv

steps here:

```
pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper
mkvirtual stratum-proxy
pip install https://github.com/slush0/stratum-mining-proxy.git
pip install zope2
```

After those step inside the virtualenv stratum-proxy was working successfully.
hope it helps